# How do I use ffmpeg with live streaming from an IP camera

Tags: ffmpeg, ip-camera, ffserver

My question is very basic because I am a newbie to all these 
technologies.

I have an IP camera connected to my internal network.

```
http://192.168.1.20/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=
```

...gives a live streaming view in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Now I want to record the live stream into a video.

The parameters to be supplied are `begin_time`, `end_time`, `format` of video etc.

How do I accomplish this?

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

what is the format of streaming protocol
You need a tool to capture the stream on server or client

- client tools to record and save video
  http: use wget rtmp: use rtmpdump
  rtsp: use openrtsp
  http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/

vlc player can also record multiple format to disk
it just saves the raw data to disk, if you need another format use ffmpeg to transkode.